# Strange jQuery behaviour while showing hiding contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of html contents called filters which is generated from database. The contents can change dynamically according to the page. I have given css IDs to each main div and appended a number with them while looping. Below is a sample snippet:

```
<div><a id="filter-1">Brands</a></div>
<div id="filter-op-1">This is option 1</div>
<div><a id="filter-2">Size</a></div>
<div id="filter-op-2">This is option 2</div>
<div><a id="filter-3">Color</a></div>
<div id="filter-op-3">This is option 3</div>
```

the ids `filter-1` and `filter-op-1` and so on are generated by the number of loops, so we dont know how much contents on the page will be generated for the filters.

I need to show/hide the filter-op-x contents by `a` click, so i wrote the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div a').click(function() { 
        var self = $(this);
        var cssId = self.attr('id');
        var child = $('div#filter-op-'+cssId);
        child.toggle();
     });
});
```

Now the problem is that it is not working in this way, but if i remove the `cssId` in js code and `-1`, `-2` etc in html, it start working, but it is hiding all contents no matter which `a` i clicked.

I dont understant what is causing this issue. Anybody can explain this problem and give some good advice how to handle it?

[JsFiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/uk1Lquuh/)

Thanks

Comment: See it working here. https://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/uk1Lquuh/1/

Comment: `self.attr('id')` would be `"filter-<Number>"` and not only the `"<Number>"` part ;)

Comment: `console.log(cssId);` will help you understand, great for future bugs aswell, to test variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make some changes in your JS code like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('div a').click(function() { 
    var self = $(this);
    var cssId = self.attr('id');
    console.log(cssId);  // This gives the `a` id.
    var id = cssId.split("-")[1]; // Split and get the number part
    console.log(id);

    var child = $('div#filter-op-'+id); // append the number part here
    child.toggle();
  });

});
```

The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/uk1Lquuh/1/

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, it was my bad and i did not paid attention to it. I understand it now what was the issue :P

Answer (score 0):

Problem found :
your cssId always return filter-1, filter-2, filter-3
and child become as 'div#filter-op-'+cssId) ==> 'div#filter-op-filter-1 which is produce wrong id of child div.

> I have added extra data attribute

Here is my working code:

HTML :

```
<div><a id="filter-1" data="1">Brands</a></div>
<div id="filter-op-1">This is option 1</div>
<div><a id="filter-2" data="2">Size</a></div>
<div id="filter-op-2">This is option 2</div>
<div><a id="filter-3" data="3">Color</a></div>
<div id="filter-op-3">This is option 3</div>
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div a').click(function() { 
        var self = $(this);
        var cssId = self.attr('data');
        var child = $('div#filter-op-'+cssId);
        child.toggle();
    });

});
```

updated [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uk1Lquuh/4/) example